# how to put a color palette in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to put a select where the user can select a color someone has idea of how to do it or if ahy a library that does

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNrql.png)

Comment: You need to research at least a little before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a colorpicker you want

```
<input name="Color Picker" type="color"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62Le2cbc/13/